# Visual Code Prettier How To Keep Space At The Start Of A Function

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have just switched over to Visual Studio Code and I am using the extension prettier.

I like it but it keeps removing the space at the beginning of a function that I would like to keep see this gif.

[image]

How do I prevent it from removing the space on save I have gone through all the options with no luck?

Comment: If you want space then drop the brace in the new line. People either want dense lines (brace in the same line) or sparse lines (brace in the separate line). Makes no sense to have it both dense and sparse at the same time.